# How to convert numeric strings in objects to numbers using typescript types

Tags: typescript

Here's the problem. Lets say I have the following object:

```
const x = {
    number1: '1',
    number2: '2',
    string1: 'one',
}
```

And the following typescript type.

```
class params {
    number1: number;
    number2: number;
    string1: string;
}
```

Is there an elegant way to convert the `x` object to the `params` type such that the properties `number1` and `number2` are cast from strings in `x` to numbers as defined by `params`?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you will have to cast it manually, the same way you would do it in JavaScript. You will need to set the variable, or property of `Params` type to ensure type checking.

```
 const y: Params = {
   number1: Number(x.number1),
   number2: Number(x.number2),
   string1: x.string1,
 }
```

In addition, if `params` is only used for type checking, I would recommend you to use `interface`, rather than `class`. This is because TypeScript classes exist at runtime, whereas interfaces are compile time only.

```
interface Params {
  number1: number;
  number2: number;
  string1: string;
}
```